# <input> is not clickable with Bootstrap 3 and col-md rows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have some "col-md-12" divs on forms that appear to "cover" preceding inputs such that they are not clickable.

I have created a bootply with Bootstrap 3.0.0 to illustrate the issue. [unclickable inputs](http://bootply.com/107074)

If I make the same bootply with bootstrap 3.0.3 then the input fields are now accessible [clickable inputs](http://bootply.com/107075#)

What I want to know is whether this is a bootstrap bug that has been fixed or whether my layout is breahing some rule or other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to put your cols into a div with the row class

```
<form>
      <div class="row">           // HERE
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label col-md-4">Home Phone:</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <input id="contact_detail_home_phone" name="contact_detail[home_phone]" size="30" type="text" value="123 5668" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label col-md-4">Work Phone:</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <input id="contact_detail_work_phone" name="contact_detail[work_phone]" size="30" type="text" value="582 5135" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">           // AND HERE
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label class="control-label">Notes:</label>
                <textarea cols="40" id="contact_detail_notes" name="contact_detail[notes]" rows="4" class="form-control"></textarea>
            </div>
      </div>   
    </form>
```

Comment: That certainly appears to fix the problem so I will mark it as answered. My problem is that different users will see different numbers of inputs prior to the notes field and so the "row" divs are not fixed but would have to be coded to be inserted programmatically for each two inputs otherwise there would be gaps.

Answer (score 0):

If you use medium size columns `col-md-` you can only have total 12 column units per each `<div class=row>`.

So, don't put more than total 12 units of `col-md` instead one `row`.

I assume this is limitation of doing layouts with columsn, floating divs and web page rendering legacy.